# What is the difference between using these two structures (Noun + noun or ('s + noun) )?

Tags: difference, possessives

Should I say "a boy's name" or "a boy name"? and if both are correct, then what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A boy's name** is the usual way of saying **the name of a boy**, using the possessive form of the noun **boy**.

However, nouns are frequently used as adjectives. When they are used this way, they are known as **attributive nouns** or **noun adjuncts** (and by other descriptions as well). Typical examples are stable door, shoe lace and eye shadow.

If you were to say that, for example, Robin or Terry or Chris, sounded to you like **boy names**, you would be using the noun **boy** attributively. People do this all the time.

Note that while many nouns are used this way in standard expressions, **boy name** is not idiomatic. Although people would know what you meant, your teacher would probably mark it as incorrect.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attributive-nouns
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct

Answer (score -1):

The difference is, the second one is incorrect. You can say **a boy's name** or **[the] name of a boy**.